# In Apache NiFi is there a way to send a message to the NiFi GUI if a flow is auto-terminated on unmatched user-defined expression?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi process RouteOnAttribute in which I have a user-defined expression to match on a Property.

I have set this to auto-terminate the FlowFile if unmatched.  It works fine.

I would like to send a message to be displayed on the NiFi GUI Process's Bulletin Indicator when unmatched. Is there a way I can configure this?   (The underlying code used for the project is Java)

Comment: force and error - eg: route to splitjson with an invalid path

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found is to route the 'unmatched' case to a LogMessage process which can be configured to output an error log message which will show in the log file and in the Bulletin indicator. Also, configure this LogMessage process to auto-terminate the FlowFile if 'success'